# How to obtain a list of Custom Objects from Firebase Database which has Multiple Object Types under the same child?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app which uses Firebase for most of the operations. There is an activity which requires a list of objects (say People) from the Firebase Database child "city". Each of the Objects are stored under a Firebase Unique Key (like `-KbhjqBQHjawWD3Eshw`). But at the end of the child "city", there is a String value, which is not under any Unique Key. So, when I call Firebase ChildEventListener, I use the statement (inside onChildAdded) `People person = dataSnapsot.getValue(People.class)`. But Since there is a String value in the child node, the app crashes. When I remove it, the app works as expected. I have scanned through my entire code, but I cannot find any place that puts the String there.

Is there any way that I can filter out the data that I need, ie, only the People objects and exclude the String so that the onChildAdded doesn't encounter it.

Or is there any way to get the Job done?

Here is the Firebase data structure example:

```
City
 |
 |_ -Kewjsbfehsuhe
 |    |
 |    |_ Name: "Delhi"
 |    |_ StateCode: "DL"
 |    |_ Population: 50000000
 |
 |_ -KSHHWbdsabfur
 |
 |_ -KDQshrgefsvre
 |
 |_ StateCode: "WB"
```

Here, I am encountering the arbitrary string StateCode. The People object consists of two Strings Name, StateCode and an int value named Population.

Comment: Have you tried to add that String field also in your pojo class?

Comment: Having trouble understanding the exact situation here. Can you include an example of the Firebase data you're describing, and also the code where you write to the database?

Comment: Instead of describing your code and data structure, please post the [minimal code and data structure (both as text, no screenshots) that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the lijnk, it is quite useful).

Comment: I don't think filtering the data is a good idea. You should find which code is putting the String there.

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your effort in going through my code. As per your suggestions, I have added the database structure. Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: OK, that's clearer but as @RosárioPereiraFernandes says, the actual problem here is not how to filter out that wrong bit of data, but how to not write it in the first place. I'd suggest including in your question the code where you're writing to Firebase(and it's worth checking if any of your listeners have some kind of firebase data writing code in them too, that can often confuse people).